# How to display the result of subtraction between two arrays in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing PHP code to show the graphical representation of data from the mysql database. 
The code works fine for the data, which is already in the database, but it doesn't appear when I try to make operations on these data.

I guess that my problem lays on the php side - the way subtract the two arrays as var_dump displays an array of values inside a while loop, but a single value outside of it. I can't get my head around it. 
My php code is as follows:

```php
require "connect.php";
    $db_conn = OpenCon();


    $dates = '';
    $data1 = '';
    $data2 = '';
    $diff = '';
    $items = array();

    $get_all_data = "SELECT * from test1";
    $total_result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $get_all_data);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($total_result)) {  
        $date = date('d, M, Y', strtotime($row['my_date']));


        $dates = $dates.'"'.$date.'",'; 
        $data1 = $data1. '"'. $row['data1'].'",';
        $data2 = $data2. '"'. $row['data2'].'",';   

        $v1 = $row['data1'];
        $v2 = $row['data2'];
        $diff=$v1-$v2;
        $diff = (string)$diff;
        $items[] = $diff;
    }
    $diff = implode(",", $items);

    $dates = trim($dates, ",");
    $data1 = trim($data1, ",");
    $data2= trim($data2, ",");
    $diff= trim($diff, ",");
```

a chunk of my script to display a graph:

```js
{ //dataset also includes data1 and data2, which are displayed correctly
  label: 'Difference',
  data: [<?php echo $diff; ?>],
  backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

In here I am trying to show "data1" and "data2" (from db) as well as the difference between them (data1-data2). The graph correctly displays 'data1' and 'data2', but the result of subtraction between data1 and data2 is not shown  at all.
I will greatly appreciate all the suggestions.

UPDATE: I updated the code and it now works as desired.

Comment: You don't do anything with the `$diff` inside the while loop. So every time you simply overwrite the old `$diff` value. Then, in the end, you're left with only one value.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your comment. I've got it sorted with simple populating of an array at the end of the loop and then I used implode to convert the format to String. What if I wanted to display an average value depending on date? Should this be done in a query?

Comment: Not if you want to show the average of your `$items` array, that would simply be: `$average = array_sum($items) / count($items);`. You could compute an average in a query as well, but why would you?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I decided to do all the calculations in the query as I think it gives me more freedom on changes and it works fine